# My Android application has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: android, logcat

When I try to run my app on an emulator, my app comes up with an error message saying

> The app has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

How do I fix this?

Here is my code:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >

        <activity 
           android:name= "com.google.ads.AdActivity"
           android:configChanges= "keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" 
        ></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".GTA5GuideActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The "Appname"Activity.java:

```
package com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class GTA5GuideActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads= "http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/gtaapp" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView android:id= "@+id/ad"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height= "wrap_content"
        ads:adUnitId= "soon"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate= "a14f8315a6c11bf"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Logcat thing:

```
04-10 08:23:55.424: D/dalvikvm(224): GC freed 510 objects / 46816 bytes in 75ms
04-10 08:23:55.534: D/AndroidRuntime(224): Shutting down VM
04-10 08:23:55.534: W/dalvikvm(224): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception          (group=0x4001b188)
04-10 08:23:55.534: E/AndroidRuntime(224): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide/com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity.onCreate(GTA5GuideActivity.java:11)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  ... 11 more
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8ca48
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-10 08:23:55.554: E/AndroidRuntime(224):  ... 20 more
04-10 08:23:55.584: I/dalvikvm(224): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:23:55.584: E/dalvikvm(224): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
04-10 08:24:22.804: D/dalvikvm(231): GC freed 537 objects / 47832 bytes in 68ms
04-10 08:24:22.913: D/AndroidRuntime(231): Shutting down VM
04-10 08:24:22.913: W/dalvikvm(231): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-10 08:24:22.913: E/AndroidRuntime(231): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide/com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity.onCreate(GTA5GuideActivity.java:11)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  ... 11 more
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8ca28
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-10 08:24:22.933: E/AndroidRuntime(231):  ... 20 more
04-10 08:24:22.953: I/dalvikvm(231): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:24:22.953: E/dalvikvm(231): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
04-10 08:24:31.884: D/dalvikvm(237): GC freed 564 objects / 48880 bytes in 92ms
04-10 08:24:31.993: D/AndroidRuntime(237): Shutting down VM
04-10 08:24:31.993: W/dalvikvm(237): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
04-10 08:24:32.003: E/AndroidRuntime(237): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide/com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class com.google.ads.AdView
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:576)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at com.DOLEnterprises.GTA5Guide.GTA5GuideActivity.onCreate(GTA5GuideActivity.java:11)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  ... 11 more
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.ads.AdView in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44e8ca28
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:466)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
04-10 08:24:32.023: E/AndroidRuntime(237):  ... 20 more
04-10 08:24:32.043: I/dalvikvm(237): threadid=7: reacting to signal 3
04-10 08:24:32.043: E/dalvikvm(237): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied
```

Comment: It can't find `com.google.ads.AdView` - have you added the .jar for Google Ads? https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals#addjar

Answer (score 1):

---EDIT---

Are you sure you have downloaded the "Ad" library and included it in your project? Class not found suggests that you have not successfully linked it to your project. Also try rebuilding your project by following the steps below .

---

Try cleaning your project... Project > Clean > Choose your Project > Ok 
Rerun your project.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that error is caused due to Typos or casting ...... Check carefully for Typos and casting ....... check for library folder name ....

Comment: what is casting and what do you mean by check for library folder name? thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

check out this

`android:configChanges` requieres all parameters to show ads in application

change the `SDK version` to `14` of your Application

mention it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="14"/>

<activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
```